# connection problem when sendign xml data from nodejs application to mssql database SP

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have been using MS SQL package for connecting `nodejs api` with MS SQL database. When i `execute` `sp` that accepts XML as input i got an connection lost error. As I thought XML data is large so there might be a problem with the `connectionTimeOut` so i increase the `connectiontimeout` but still got an error. But I didn't get an connection error when i `execute` other `SP`. what's the reason for this connection lost error ?

In config object in I have increased the `connectionTimeOut` value to 30000.

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: Yes i have been using nodejs and mssql package to connecto to mssql database.

Answer (score 0):

If `AUTO_CLOSE` option enable on database level, set it to `OFF`, you can use following query.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```

Once it's set to `OFF` (`select name, is_auto_close_on from sys.databases`). Try to run `sp` again.

In-case it's the same issue, you need investigate on your procedure to identity which part of query, Tables, Table's Indexes are causing the issue..

Comment: It still gives the same error but when I run that sp from database it works fine but It only create an error when i try to execute that SP from my nodejs app.